# POSTING XML USING GUZZLE CLIENT LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I am a laravel junior developer and i have been using gazzle http for handling my requests, now i have a task of integrating Collections to a system. The provided API only wants me to post XML data. When i use Json, it works well, but now i have a task of posting xml through gazzle. how can i do it.

with Json,

```
$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://app.apiproviders.com/api/payment/donate', [
        'form_params'   => [
        'name'          => 'TIG Test',
        'amount'        => $amount,
        'number'        => str_replace('+', '',$this->senders_contact),
        'chanel'        => 'TIG',
        'referral'      => str_replace('+', '',$this->senders_contact)
        ]
        ]);  

the desired XML format to post:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AutoCreate>
    <Request>
        <Method>acdepositfunds</Method>
        <NonBlocking></NonBlocking>
        <Amount>500</Amount>
        <Account>256702913454</Account>
        <AccountProviderCode></AccountProviderCode>
        <Narrative>Testing the API</Narrative>
        <NarrativeFileName>receipt.doc</NarrativeFileName>
        <NarrativeFileBase64>aSBhbSBwYXlpbmcgNjAwMDAgc2hpbGxpbmdz</NarrativeFileBase64>
    </Request>
</AutoCreate>

how can i pass this xml to gazzle in laravel??
```

Comment: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#body not much more to tell here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a same problem a while ago, and I found a good solution using [AttayToXml](https://github.com/spatie/array-to-xml) package. All you need to do is to create an `array` of your data:

```
$array = [
    'Request' => [
        'Method' => 'value',
        'NonBlocking' => 'value',
        'Amount' => 'value',
        //and so on...
    ]
];
```

Then, you convert this array to xml, using the convert() method, where you pass the name of the root element of your xml:

```
$xml = ArrayToXml::convert($array, 'AutoCreate');
```

And this will create your desired xml:

```
<AutoCreate>
    <Request>
        <Method>acdepositfunds</Method>
        <NonBlocking></NonBlocking>
        <Amount>500</Amount>
        //and so on...
    </Request>
</AutoCreate>
```

And then, send it through Guzzle client with something like this, which I used in on of my projects:

```
$request = $httpClient->post($yourUrl, [
                    'body' => $xml,
                    'http_errors' => true,
                    'verify' => false,
                    'defaults' => ['verify' => false]
                ]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, how ever, now after doing like so, it returns a response like failure to login. Meaning its not reading the Login credentials i have supplied. *** i didn't include these credentials in the sample code above***

Comment: I finally figured it out. i had to add                                                                       'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=UTF8',
            ],  'body' => $xml, //etc. thank you

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond earlier, was pretty busy. No problem, glad I could help. If my answer helped you solve your issue, accept it, so people with same issues could find it easier.

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php
~~~

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

~~~

$xml = new \SimpleXMLElement('<Hogeattribute></Hogeattribute>');
$xml->addChild('hogeId', 'hoge1');

$response = Http::withBody(
    $xml->asXML(),
    'text/xml'
)->post('https://hoge');

$json = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($response->body()));
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

https://readouble.com/laravel/8.x/ja/http-client.html
https://qiita.com/megponfire/items/e2cfa22216073dd5d596

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).